# Finding R2 and slope for individual sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

I have data in columns highlighted in green and I need to use Python to get to columns highlighted in yellow and plots. I know how to plot data in python using matplotlib or find out slope and R2 using scipy when I have to find out slopes and R2 for an entire column. However, as can be seen from the attached image, I need four different slopes and four different R2 and four different plots for four different countries.[image]

Data is in green highlight. Solution is in yellow highlight and four plots are shown. I tried looking into many forums online but find it difficult to find solution to this. Thanks for reading.

PS: I have used random data in x-axis and y-axis.

Edit:

The code I have been using to calculate slope is:

```
import numpy, scipy,pandas as pd, matplotlib
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress
import scipy.stats
import copy
df=pd.read_excel("I:/Python/Excel.xlsx")
df.head();

xyDataPairs = df[['x-axis', 'y-axis']].values.tolist();
slope = linregress(x, y)[0];  # slope in units of y / x

print('best slope=', slope)
```

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to find out. Could you please paste your code?

Comment: @Marouen, I pasted the code which helps calculate the slope.

Comment: what are x and y? they appear the first time in linregress.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
df.groupby('Country', as_index=True)['x-axis','y-axis'].apply(linregress)
```

EDIT

To plot data by categories in subplots, `seaborn` has intuitive syntax.

```
import seaborn as sn
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)

sns.catplot(x="x-axis", y="y-axis",
            col="Country", aspect=.6,
             data=df);
plt.show()
```

Comment: I used the following code:                                                                   
    xyDataPairs = df[['x-axis', 'y-axis']].values.tolist();
    df.groupby('Country',as_index=True)['x-axis', 'y-axis'].apply(linregress)
    slope = linregress(x, y)[0];  # slope in units of y / x
    print('best slope:', slope); # I am getting slope for entire column and not for individual countries

Comment: @Rahul007 do the following :
`res=df.groupby('Country', as_index=True)['x-axis','y-axis'].apply(linregress);
print(res)`

Comment: Oh yes, this solution worked, but there is no mention of slope, R2 etc on the header. It is just seen as (2.3,200.3,0.95...

Comment: it is the same order of output of linregress, so the first number is slope.

Comment: is there some way to get linregres headers at the top? Also, how do I convert this result to csv or xlsx?

Comment: `res.to_csv('result.csv')` is what you want

Comment: that worked! Now last part of the question was how do I get to four plots from raw data as in my original question. Data to the right hand side of the image? I know how to plot data in matplotlib for entire column. However, to plot per country is confusing.

Comment: you will need seaborn to plot data by categories in subplot. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am getting this error on running the code:                                                                                                               "AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'catplot'
"